# Load page template with custom content using a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, page-template

I want to load the `page.php` template with the content I specify (using variables and not from the database) if the request contains a particular query string.

So lets say a user requests `example.com/?var1=str1` the page template should be displayed with the title and content I specify using variables.

This is the pseudo code of what I'm trying to achieve

```
<?php
function my_page_function() {
if($_REQUEST['var1'] == "str1")
{
$title="This will be the title of the default page template";
$content="This content will be displayed on the default page template.";
//Load the page.php here with the title and content specified in the variables above
}
}
add_action("template_redirect","my_page_function");
?>
```

I wish to use this code in a plugin, so it should work with any theme's page.php.

Comment: Are you properly registering your query variable, or just relying on `$_REQUEST`?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that with filters on [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) and [`the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title):

```
function wpa_content_filter( $content ) {
    if( isset( $_REQUEST['var1'] ) && $_REQUEST['var1'] == "str1" ) {
        return 'This content will be displayed on the default page template.';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpa_content_filter', 999 );
```

Comment: Thanks Milo. You're almost close to what I want but the only problem is this content is displayed using the `index.php` template. How do I show this using the `page.php` template?

Comment: You'll have to force a specific template via the [template redirect action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) or one of the [template filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Filter_Hierarchy). but keep in mind that a theme may not have a page.php template, it's not required for a correctly functioning theme.

Comment: +1, since this is the end result I came to as well, too. What I'm confused about, though, is why and how the content is being displayed using the `index.php` template file, rather than using `page.php`.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Milo and Chip. I found what I wanted [here](http://davejesch.com/wordpress/wordpress-tech/creating-virtual-pages-in-wordpress/) I didn't know the exact word (virtual page) of what I wanted. After googling for a long time I found the phrase "without having the page stored in the database" highlighted in the above link which was what I exactly wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Create the template file within your Plugin, e.g. `template-pluginname.php`, then hook into `template_include` and tell WordPress to use it:

```
function wpse114181_template_include( $template ) {
    return ( '' != get_query_var( 'plugin_key' ) ? plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'template-plugin.php' : $template );
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse114181_template_include' );
```

Note: this requires that you register your query variable using [`add_query_arg()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg), but is safer than relying on `$_REQUEST` directly.

### Edit

Based on this comment:

> The only problem with this code is that as I said earlier I want to plugin to work properly with any theme. So if I design a template file myself it wouldn't look like the currently activated theme's page.php

If you are absolutely intent on overriding the Post Title and Post Content, then you can use the `the_title` and `the_content` filters:

```
function wpse114181_filter_the_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_page() && '' != get_query_var( 'plugin_key' ) ) {
        return 'Your Post Title Here';
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse114181_filter_the_title' );

function wpse114181_filter_the_content( $content ) {
    if ( is_page() && '' != get_query_var( 'plugin_key' ) ) {
        return 'Your Post Content Here';
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse114181_filter_the_content' );
```

Comment: +1 as relying on `$_REQUEST` won't work in CLI environments, during cron jobs, etc.

Comment: Thanks Chip. The only problem with this code is that as I said earlier I want to plugin to work properly with any theme. So if I design a template file myself it wouldn't look like the currently activated theme's page.php

Comment: See edited answer. You can use the `the_title` and `the_content` filters.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chip.<br/>You've used the `is_page()` function so the request URL has to contain a page_id too right? Something like `example.com/?page_id=2&plugin_key=abc` <br />But I want the code to "load the page template" without a page_id being requested.<br />In other words the URL will contain only the custom query variable.

Comment: Inside the Loop (where these filters are applied), the `$query` object is already set - which means that query conditionals such as `is_page()` are also already set.